# Event Listeners in devtools: I see in Firefox, not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

In Firefox I see this (good):
[image: firefox-devtools-nodes-attached-event]

And I perfectly see attached event for this node.

But in Chrome for the same node I see (bad):
[image: Chrome devtools: event listeners]

In Firefox I see that click will be handled by `filterpro.min.js`, but in Chrome I see links to jQuery and `include.postload.js`. Firefox wins?

Of course for Chrome I can use bookmarklet [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2):
[image: Visual Event bookmarklet]
...but this is strange - in Chrome I really can't find attached listeners for this node?